# Google maps driving mode url scheme not working on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am trying to call the external `Google Maps` app from my  `Android` app.

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + stringLatitude + "," + stringLongitude + "&daddr=" + latitud + "," + longitud+"&dirflg=d"));

startActivity(mIntent);
```

It works perfectly on `Android 2.3.6`.

But not on `Android 4.2`, the first time I click in the button that executes that code `Google Maps` is opened correctly but nothing about Driving mode appears there.

But once I go back to the main app an I click again in the button all works fine. It only fails on the first attempt.

I cannot understand what is going on

Any clue?

Comment: I can't believe in. really it's happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using following code working fine on android 4.2

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
           Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+a+","+b+"&daddr="+c+","+d+"&mode=driving"));
i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I have also tested it on `Android 4.3` and it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the mode key for motorbike?

Comment: @YousufSohail It's driving. Please refer at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes

Comment: @ChetakBhimani it should be different than "driving" as we get both option in google maps and they show different routes for "driving" and "motorbike"